# Get data from a reactive container

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

From the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#data), I get that I need to use a reactive data container around my component to retrieve the currently logged in user (if one exists), but how do I get the data from that container?

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export default FooContainer = createContainer(() => {
  return {
    user: Meteor.user()
  };
}, class FooComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<div>{ /* this.data.user ??? */ }</div>);
  }
});
```

How do I get the data returned from the container function inside my `render` method?

Comment: Have you tried `this.props.user`?

Comment: I *just* realized that when `console.log(this);` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you returned a `user` key in your container, therefore your data will be accessible via your `this.props.user` prop in your component.

Just make sure you add something like this to your container:

```
export default FooContainer = createContainer(() => {
const subscription = Meteor.subscribe("userData");
subscription.ready() ? Session.set("dataReady", true) : Session.set("dataReady", false);

  return {
    user: Meteor.user()
  };
}
```

and in your render method:

```
 render() {
    if(Session.get("dataReady")){
return (<div>{ /* this.data.user ??? */ }</div>);
}
  }
```

Trust me, it will save you a lot of headache and a lot of errors in the future. This will make sure your data is 100% ready before it's called and rendered in your component.

Oh, also assuming you have autopublish removed, publish the particular user's data in order to subscribe to it like I showed above:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

Just a heads up.